# How do I point GitHub for Windows to my existing repository folders?

Tags: windows, git, github

I installed [GitHub for Windows](http://windows.github.com/), and it's a very smooth program (looks exactly like any of the Live programs). However, it lists my GitHub repositories and wants me to clone it to `%USERPROFILE%/Documents/GitHub`. I don't want to clone my repository. I want to tell GitHub where to find the locations of the repositories I've currently been using to push to GitHub. Is this possible?

Answer (score 6):

Drag your existing repositories into the GitHub app's window.

Comment: I did that, but it still thinks that the repository I dragged into GitHub is **different** than the GitHub repository, i.e. not a clone.

Comment: Today, just a few minutes ago, I tried to do something I *know* I have done before - just drag and drop a git folder into the client. This time it didn't work. So I entered my github usr/pwd and rebooted the machine. It then worked.